# Apex to return custom metadata and dynamic object data

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, dynamic-soql, custom-metadata

I am looking to have a lightning web component that returns data from an object based on the record I am on that i can display on a lightning record page . I am exploring programmatically pulling a custom metadata type record so that it can be configurable. I have created the custom metadata type record already.

I am aware that in addition the Lightning web component, I need an apex class in order to query the custom metadata type and data. I wish i could do this all with a LWC, but when i do that, i can only return the actual value in the Custom metadata type and not the actual object's dynamic field.

Example: I would like to return the Case object's field "Subject" in the lightning component along with some static text. e.g. (if the Case's subject = "Urgent Matter" then on the case record, i want that to show)
any help is appreciated around the apex part - thanks!

so far in my apex class i have:

```
public with sharing class Case_Name {
public static void getCaseMetaData(Id recordId){

    String sObjectName = recordId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    List<Case_Name__mdt> caseName = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName, Text__c, Text_Fields__c, from Case_Name__mdt where DeveloperName = 'Casename'];
```

Comment: You can use [getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record) by simply having a record Id and the fields you want, and you can [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) to get fields, etc.

Comment: Thank you- i have used getrecord in my LWC but am wanting to pull custom metadata types so it can be configurable by a Salesforce Admin if they want to change the output without touching the code. is it possible to do this still with just a LWC to pull the field's data with custom metadatatype?

Comment: You could, yes, using getRecord and getObjectInfo.

Comment: You could also just use the XML configuration file to allow admins to pass properties into your LWC in record pages, communities, home page, etc, via lightning app builder / community builder: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags